# Why has no-one deleted this answer

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

It is obviously meant in an insulting way, and the fact you get the joke (it's not a difficult one to make) does not make it funny.

[Has anyone described etc. Ataraxia from not asking needless questions?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/94135/has-anyone-described-etc-ataraxia-from-not-asking-needless-questions?noredirect=1#)

And the fact you agree with the joke is making you seem like a total cretin

---

More generally, my complaint is that every-time I come away from this site, I have to try and remind myself that I not universally belittled by people, even intelligent people. Something has gone quite wrong, for me to need to feel that way.

Comment: you do not have the authority necessary to decide there is no such thing as peace from not asking needless questions. for the love of your philosophy gods, please stop thinking you do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

1. There are very few active reviewers on this site
2. The flag was cast 8 hours ago
3. There is something called sleep that humans need from time to time. And humans have *lives* beyond lurking on this site 24/7. Moderators are humans, too, you know.

Off to delete the answer, bye...

Comment: ok thanks. and sorry for being all over the place. bye